# understanding static member function and variable and destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, static-members

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    static int Retr();  // Static member function
    //~Test(); // Test destructor
    Test(); // Default constructor
private:
    static int count; // Static member variable
    int i;
};

int Test::count = 0; // Initialization

int main()
{
    Test obj;

    cout << Test::Retr() << endl;
    // The result should be 1 but prints two

    return 0;
}
Test::Test() : i(1) { Retr(); }

int Test::Retr()
{
    return ++count;
}

/*
Test::~Test()
{
    count--;
}
*/
```

I'm practising about usage of static member function and variable. I have a static member function that counts and returns how many objects are constructed. It should show `1` for this example but it shows `2`. I don't understand why it happens. However, the destructor decreases the counter end of scope for every constructed objects. Doesn't it? So, the result using with destructor should be `0`. But, I can't get the expected results. Could someone explain?

Edited what about not working of destructor ? Solved

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    static int Retr();  // Static member function
    ~Test(); // Test destructor
    Test(); // Default constructor
private:
    static int count; // Static member variable
    int i;
};

int Test::count = 0; // Initialization

int main()
{
    Test obj[2];

    cout << Test::Retr() << endl;
    // The result should be 0 because of destructor but prints 2

    return 0;
}
Test::Test() : i(1) { ++count; }

int Test::Retr()
{
    return count;
}


Test::~Test()
{
    --count;
    cout << Test::Retr() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating

```
    Test obj;
```

It calls the constructor and increments 1

and again you are calling

```
    Test::retr()
```

It also increments 1.

If you want to check the behavior of your class you can add additional function as

```
void testFunction(){
    Test obj[2];
    std::cout << Test::Retr() << std::endl; // count became 3
}
int main(){

     testFunction();
      // Obj destructed here count became 1
     std::cout << Test::Retr() << std::endl;
     // It will again increment and count will be 2
}
```

Comment: Your destructor will decrement count 2 times and will leave 1, which is increased because you called Test Retr() separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test::Test() : i(1) { Retr(); }
```

When you have created an object, It also calls `retr()` function. Thats increments count; And again you call `retr()` to show..

Your destructor is working.Call `Test::Retr()` to check count after destruction.

```
Test::~Test()
{
    --count;
    cout << Test::Retr() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to understand what is a static member function.

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the program.

So your entire program will only have one instance of `count` (Which is initialized to 0)

Let us look at the code in the main function, you're creating an object of the `class Test`. Hence the constructor gets called, which inturn calls the `static int Retr()` function. Hence `count` is now 1. Now,

```
cout << Test::Retr() << endl;
```

Calls `Retr()` again, hence it increments `count` and returns the value. Hence 2 is returned.

As far as the destructor is concerned, it is not called before the `cout`. It will be called only when `obj` goes out of scope, which will happen only when the main function is completed.